# With New Photos app on Mac, how do I manage photos on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, imac, photos, disk-space

I have 2 iMacs at the office and at home; an iPhone; and an iPad.

I recently installed the new Photos app on both iMacs. In both cases, I’m using iCloud Photo Library. So, any new photos I take on my iPhone appear on both iMacs. This is great — now I know my photos are backed up (both on iCloud and on two iMacs), and they're available from any machine on which I'd like to access them.

In other words, as I understand it, Photos and iCloud are keeping all my devices in sync.

The problem is that I don't want to keep all my photos on my iPhone. Once the photo is saved to iCloud and my iMacs, I’d like to be able to delete it from my iPhone, ***while keeping it on both my iMacs and on iCloud***. As it stands now, if I delete a photo from my iPhone, it also disappears from my iMacs.

So my question is, how can I delete photos from my iPhone without deleting them from iCloud or my iMacs? Is there a setting that makes this the default behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behavior is for iCloud Photo Library not to store full-size versions of your photos on your iPhone and iPad:

[image: iCloud Photo Library Settings]

The theory is that only thumbnails are stored on your iPhone/iPad until you decide to view/edit/share the photo, at which point a device-optimized or full-size version of your photo is downloaded from iCloud.

(Note: I know a full-size copy is downloaded when you edit/share, but it appears that if your iPhone has plenty of space it will download a full-size copy for viewing as well, as opposed to just a device-optimized version. This is likely to avoid having to do a second download later if you decide to share the photo.)

When you start running low on space, iOS will begin pruning less-accessed photos and return to simply thumbnails or device-optimized versions of those.

All of this happens automatically in the background and you shouldn't have to worry about managing space yourself.

Answer (score 4):

iCloud Photo Library doesn't support doing that. All your photos have to be on all your devices where you've enabled it and deleting a photo anywhere deletes it everywhere.

Unless you have a huge library, it shouldn't be a big issue. My library has 11K photos and 300 videos but only takes a little over 2GB of space on my iPhone. The total space used for photos & videos might actually go down as full-sized images taken on the iPhone or synced to it get replaced by "device-specific" resolutions.

Comment: This question I asked yesterday is somewhat relevant, if others do not see as so I will delete it. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182833/icloud-photo-library-not-optimizing